# Re-queuing messages at the end of a queue when a transaction rolled back

Tags: spring-amqp

I'm consuming messages asynchronously with a `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`. That messages calls methods on my service layer, and I intentionally throw an exception in order to test the rollback of the transaction. I would want the message to be send back to the end of the queue, however it doesn't happen. Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have setChannelTransacted to true and a RabbitTransactionManager set on your SimpleMessageListenerContainer. It would be helpful if you posted your configuration. Also, when throwing an exception make sure you aren't throwing an AMQPRejectAndDontRequeueException because that explicitly tells spring-amqp to not requeue regardless of your overall configuration.

```
@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer()
{
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer result = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    result.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    result.setTransactionManager(rabbitTxManager);
    result.setChannelTransacted(true);
    result.setMessageListener(myMessageListener);
    result.setConcurrentConsumers(1);
    result.setQueues(myQueues);
    return result;
}
```